# How can I print 5 to 2 decimal place implied?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim amount as Decimal = 5 
Console.WriteLine("{0, D2}" , amount)
```

Output should Display 
500

Comment: What? You want that a value is multipled by 100?

Comment: Please see the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about the current question asked.

Comment: Output of `500` is not to two decimal places, as your question's title states is the objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that with a standard format specifier you have to use a trick. Use the [percent-format-specifier "P"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-percent-p-format-specifier) after you removed the percent-symbol from the `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
Dim percentWithoutSign = CType(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone, Numberformatinfo)
percentWithoutSign.PercentSymbol = ""
```

Now you can use this `Numberformatinfo` wherever you want to display a value as percentage but without the percent-symbol (`P0` means no decimal places but orginial value * 100):

```
Dim amount as Decimal = 5 
Dim result = amount.ToString("P0", percentWithoutSign)
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried that, i did not get the right result. D2 gives me 5.00 however i need 500 without the decimal point